# Reading Data from HDFS of different machine using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I have to read data stored in HDFS of a different machine and needs to be accessed through Spark for being read.

How to do that? Full HDFS address along with port doesn't seem to work.

Anyone did it before?

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o244.load.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From Sandeeps-MacBook-Pro.local/192.168.50.188 to ec2-35-154-242-76.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:714)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:388)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282
```

Comment: Are you using something like this : "hdfs://[namnode hostname/IP]:8020/[fullPath] ? Here I am assuming your nameservice port is configured to 8020 port

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same "hdfs://[namnode hostname/IP]:8020/[fullPath]" andI tried 8020, but still didn't work, tried other ports like 9000, 50070, etc.

Comment: Can you test if you can use Hadoop HDFS API to access the name service without using Spark ? I wonder whether are you even able to connect from your machine. Maybe its a firewall issue

Comment: How to update/fix the firewall issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reach the host ec2-35-154-242-76.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000, but the ConnectionRefused error indicates that is not available.

Because it seems to be an AWS host, you need to create some firewall rules to enable  your IP  Sandeeps-MacBook-Pro.local/192.168.50.188 access your cluster. As your IP is private, I'm afraid that you will need to figure out the public one.